# VirtualBox Shared Folder Windows 10 Host, Ubuntu Guest

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, mount, troubleshooting

I am using Virtual Box 6.0.14, Windows 10 version 1903, and Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

I am trying to set a shared folder in Ubuntu as my guest OS, but for some reason, I can't

I have installed Virtual Box's Guest Additions, Virtual Box Extension Pack, and still nothing ...

This is what I am doing:

[image]

I have already restarted my computer, but the shared folder doesn't appear .. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you share the drive on the host machine to the user name of the Ubuntu machine?  Connect by IP address.  Connect as smb://192.168.x.y  and see if this connects. I tried this with Ubuntu 18 LTS and Windows 10 Pro V1909. The connection came up.

Comment: no .. it does not connect

Comment: It may be that Virtual Box cannot manage this

Comment: I have already done that, but in Windows 10 as guest and Ubuntu as host ..

Comment: You may need to set up Samba in the Ubuntu machine. https://adrianmejia.com/how-to-set-up-samba-in-ubuntu-linux-and-access-it-in-mac-os-and-windows/

Comment: I don't need Samba .. Even if I share a folder in the same drive, is not shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already solved it .. It was a very dumb mistake .. I wasn't installing the **"Guest Additions"** correctly. I had a messegge simmilar to this:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.2.12 Guest Additions for Linux........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the gcc make perl packages from your distribution.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel modules will not be replaced until the system is restarted
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
Press Return to close this window...
```

So, all I have to do is run the next commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc make perl dkms
reboot
```

Install again the **"Guest Additions"**

And do again the normal procedure to share folders .. It doesn't matter if it is a whole Drive